# Calculating monthly remaining balance after weekly payments in a query

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I'm looking for a way to calculate monthly remaining balance of a loan after weekly payments, all in a `SELECT query` that looks like

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN frequency = 'Monthly' THEN balance * (1+ 1/12/100 * rate) - freq_based_payment
        WHEN frequency = 'Biweekly' THEN...
        WHEN frequency = 'Weekly' THEN...
    END AS expected_balance
...
FROM table
```

I could do the code like that for example but i'm searching for a better and cleaner way, because in 'Weekly' it's gonna get ridiculous.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN frequency = 'Monthly' THEN balance * (1+ 1/12/100 * rate) - freq_based_payment
        WHEN frequency = 'Biweekly' THEN
            (balance * (1+ 1/26/100 * rate) - freq_based_payment) * 
            (1+ 1/26/100 * rate) - freq_based_payment
        WHEN frequency = 'Weekly' THEN...
    END AS expected_balance
...
FROM table
```

I'm new to SAS and `proc sql` and so far, I've found `MORT()` but it's not useful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "monthly remaining balance ... after weekly payments"? Another tip as well, there aren't 26 fortnights in a year, but I see division by 26 - something to think about if you are doing anything financial, because it is usually important that sums add up precisely, and if "rate" is a yearly figure then these calculations may not produce correct results.

Comment: Please update with some sample data and desired output. You might want to look at `sum() over` in the meantime

Comment: @Steve yeah i put 26 just to simplify, I use 26.07142855 actually.

I'm refactoring some code and each end of the month, they have a table with balance and expected balance, to be able to calculate prepayments if balance_of_next_month != expected balance.

It's a bit of a fiasco tbh, but I can't change the structure.

Comment: @JohnHC If I have a balance of 500$ and biweekly payments of 20$, I'm looking to have 465,67$ in the expected_balance_for_next_month. The actual code in place doesn't calculate it right, giving 465,65$...and the difference gets way bigger with bigger numbers.

Comment: @wimz Edit your question provide sample data and expected output. This will be in table form.

Answer (score 0):

@wimz, following from the comments, are you refactoring the code or re-writing it?

Using values like 26.071... (or any other fraction) is flawed from an accountancy point of view - accountancy calculations are often far more difficult than first appears, unless you have been given explicit licence to use approximate values for a financial calculation (virtually unheard of!).

If you have fortnightly payments of $20 and a starting balance of $500, the balance due next month depends on the start date of the fortnightly cycle, the length of the month, and various other factors.

Consider February for example - you can make payments 1st and 15th, and the next payment falls either on 29th-Feb or 01st-Mar. Only leap Februaries can contain 3 payments, and only when one of those payments falls on the 1st. All other months can contain between 2 and 3 payments, with no simple cycle.

How then is it possible to calculate an accurate balance for a particular month, when taking only a simple division of a rate, and no reference to the start date of the weekly cycle?

Comment: I completely understand what you mean and agree with it. Their calculations are absolutely flawed and they know it but they won't do anything about it.

I'm an intern and they don't care about my opinion, even if they know they are wrong. Thanks for trying to help guys, but I'll let that one go. I'll use their code and that's it.

Comment: @wimz, ah well, if you're an intern, it will be a lesson on the quality nowadays of most analysis done and most software written!